# SWT: Nested Layouts with ScrolledComposite exceeds available space

Tags: java, layout, swt, grid-layout, scrolledcomposite

I want to build a Master-Detail layout for one of my applications using SWT.

Container, Content, Sidebar and Part1 are Composite instances.
Scrolled is a ScrolledComposite

The desired layout is something like:

```
+--Container-------------------------------------+
|+--Content----------------------++--Sidebar----+|
||                               ||+--Part1----+||
||                               |||           |||
||                               |||           |||
||                               |||           |||
||                               |||           |||
||                               |||           |||
||                               ||+-----------+||
||                               ||+--Scrolled-+||
||                               |||           |||
||                               |||           |||
||                               |||           |||
||                               |||           |||
||                               |||           |||
||                               ||+-----------+||
|+-------------------------------++-------------+|
+------------------------------------------------+
```

The Content should grab all the space horizontally and vertically that is available.

The sidebar is basically a container for Part1 and Scrolled which should be of equal height.

Scrolled is the container for a Composite containing a dynamic number of sub items which are arranged in the content composite. Because there can be a large variation of the number of sub-items, this Composite should be scrollable.

I have now implemented this in the following way:

- Container has a GridLayout with 2 colums.
- Inside of that the content has FILL_BOTH behaviour and grabs also all HORIZONTAL/VERTICAL space.
- The sidebar has a FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL) and contains the Part1 and Scrolled Childs.

**Problem:**
When putting a lot of items into the scrolled composite and the layout just overflows the available space and there is no scrolling available where it should be.

When I use a FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL) for the container the behaviour is as desired, since there is a scrolling and everything is "inside bounds".

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour also when using a GridLayout because I want the content to grab most of the space.

Attached the current test SWT snippet:

```
public class Scrolled {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,false));
        //shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

        Composite content = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        content.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT,SWT.CENTER,false,false));

        Composite sidebar = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        sidebar.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
        sidebar.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT,SWT.CENTER,false,false));

        Composite cc = new Composite(sidebar, SWT.BORDER);

        ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(sidebar, SWT.BORDER
                | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
        sc.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,true));

        Composite c = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
        c.setSize(400, 400);
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            new Button(c, SWT.PUSH).setText("Text");
        }

        sc.setMinSize(c.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
        sc.setContent(c);
        sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        sc.setExpandVertical(true);
        sc.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

seems like I found the solution.

Seems to be the case that a Composite has to take `GRAB_EXCESS_VERTICAL` to be limited to available width. Otherwise the component gets assigned the preferred height which is the maximum height to display all at once.

The following code changes did the trick:

```
content.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,true,true));

sidebar.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,false,true));
```